# Trigger keyboard event in vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to follow [currently recommended way](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createEvent) of triggering dom events (using event constructors that is) and it does not work for me (in Chrome)

This is my code (http://jsfiddle.net/artemave/shg7ot58/):

```
document.addEventListener(function(e) {
    alert("hallo");
});

var e = new KeyboardEvent("keydown", {
    key: "Escape", // keyCode: 27 also does not work
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true
});
document.dispatchEvent(e);
```

Comment: You need to add `keydown` to your `document.addEventListener`. http://jsfiddle.net/shg7ot58/1/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add event type, `keydown` to the `addEventListener` method to listen for your custom dispatched event.

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    alert("hallo");
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/shg7ot58/1/